# Objective C - Array With Numbers

Tags: objective-c, arrays, int

Is there a nicer way to fill an array with numbers than what I use?
It's crazy how much I got to write just to fill an array with numbers so they can be used for a calculation in a loop. This is easier in other C based languages like PHP, As3, or Java.

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:  
                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:1000],[NSNumber numberWithInt:237], [NSNumber numberWithInt:2673], nil];

int total = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < [myArray count]; i += 1 ){
    total += [[myArray objectAtIndex: i]intValue];
    NSLog(@"%i", total);
}
```

Hopefully there is a shorter way... I just want to fill an array with ints... cant be that hard

Comment: None of those languages are "C-based".

Comment: For some things you want `NSNumber` objects, they can be stored in collections and automatically encoded/decoded to files/network streams, etc. For other things you may want good old C ints in a C array, for super-fast lookup and usage (for example a frequency table in an audio processing function). In Objective-C you can choose which is the most appropriate, it supports both.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess you have to use NSNumber for an NSArray. If you want to use ints I guess you'd have to use a c array:

```
NSInteger myArray[20];

for (int i=0;i<20;i++) {
  int num=myArray[i];

  //do something
 }
```

NSNumber though is I guess the better approach for this language.
At least you can do fast enumeration to shorten code a bit:

```
for (NSNumber *n in myArray) {
 int num = [n intValue];

 //do something....

}
```

---

**EDIT:**

The question has been asked 3 years ago. There have been new literals established to make it easier to create objects like NSNumbers or NSArrays:

```
NSNumber *n = @100;
```

or

```
NSArray *array = @[@100,@50,@10];
```

Comment: The literal syntax described is already available: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html

Comment: Sure... its 3 years later :)  I edited the answer to make it un-ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Nice short alternative for looping specific integers:

```
NSArray *numbers = [@"1000,237,2673" componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
for (NSString *i in numbers) {
    [i intValue]; // Do something.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First start with a C array:

```
NSInteger myCArray = { 1000, 237, 2673 };
// calculate number of elements
NSUInteger myCArrayLength = sizeof(myCArray) / sizeof(NSInteger;
```

Second, *if* you need an `NSArray` loop through this array and create one:

```
NSMutableArray *myNSArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:myCArrayLength];
for(NSUInteger ix = 0; ix < myCArrayLength; ix++)
   [myNSArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:myCArray[ix]];
```

You can wrap the second piece of code up as a category on `NSArray` if you're doing it a lot.

Answer (score 0):

too late. but u can do the following too.

```
int total = 0;
nsarray *myArray = @[@1.8,@100,@299.8]; 
for(nsnumber *num in myArray){
 total+=num;
}
```

Comment: It looks like this syntax is covered in the accepted answer already - what value does putting it again have?